# How we can write data to a postgres DB table using R?

Tags: r, postgresql

I need to write data to a postgres DB table using R. If a data  exist for an ID in the table, data should be updated otherwise new data should append to the table.

I tried this using 'RPostgreSQL' Package I got this error message

```
dbWriteTable(con, 'credit', credit,overwrite=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)<br>

Error in postgresqlWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...) :overwrite and append cannot both be TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use overwrite and append at once. If use overwrite command as follows, it will truncate the table and rewrite the data.

```
dbWriteTable(con, 'credit', credit,overwrite=TRUE,row.names=FALSE)
```

If use append it will Add the rows. But it won't update your results.

```
dbWriteTable(con, 'credit', credit,row.names=FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Note that `overwrite=TRUE` drops and recreates the table rather than truncating.