# write data to table using RPostgreSQL without altering structure

Tags: r, postgresql

A thing I ran into using the RPostgreSQL package is that dbWriteTable(… overwrite=TRUE) seems to destroy existing table structure (datatypes and constraints), and dbRemoveTable() is equivalent to DROP table.

So I’ve used:

```
ltvTable <- "the_table_to_use"
dfLTV <- dataframe(x,y,z)
sql_truncate <- paste("TRUNCATE ", ltvTable) ##unconditional DELETE FROM…
res <- dbSendQuery(conn=con, statement=sql_truncate)
dbWriteTable(conn=con, name=ltvTable, value=dfLTV, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
```

Is the TRUNCATE step necessary, or is there a dbWriteTable method that overwrites just the content not the structure?

I experience different behaviour from the answer offered by  [Manura Omal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5307871/manura-omal)  to [How we can write data to a postgres DB table using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32269616/how-we-can-write-data-to-a-postgres-db-table-using-r), as overwrite=TRUE does not appear to truncate first.

I'm using: RPostgreSQL 0.4-1; PostgreSQL 9.4

best wishes - JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know overwrite=T does 3 things:

- DROPs the table
- CREATES the table
- fills table with new data

So if you want to preserve the structure, then you need the Truncate step.
Different behaviour might be caused by existence or non-existence of foreign keys preventing the DROP table step.